# After upgrade from Debian 10 Buster to Debian 11 Bullseye security updates 404 not found

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, debian-buster

Doing recommended upgrade path, TL;DR:

Backup data, then

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Also disable all non main stream packages if any.

Then preparing APT for new distribution:

```
sudo sed -i 's/buster/bullseye/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i 's/buster/bullseye/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

The first command shows error:

```
apt update
...
Err:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye/updates Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 25):

This is regarding change in Debian 11 repository structure. RTFM requires time, so bump answer here:

> For Debian bullseye, the security suite is now named bullseye-security
> instead of codename/updates and users should adapt their APT
> source-list files accordingly when upgrading.

Thus execute one more command:

```
sed -i 's/bullseye\/updates/bullseye-security/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now apt update works great again, and you can continue with upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs
sudo apt full-upgrade
reboot
```

Check if system is upgraded:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
```

After successful reboot, you can remove old kernel:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-4.19*
```

Also review log files, for error messages of conflicting configurations or other issues.

Issue list is here: https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.html

Comment: I like the new Debian repository structure, much less confusing than buster/updates and buster-updates imho.

Comment: I'd like to think they would just make a simple symlink on the server side and a package to update the apt sources list on the machine side to prevent these kinds of issues...

Comment: -1 because answer is fragile.  If user has made any manual changes to sources.list, it might not work, and user not given the next thing to try.   c.f. [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1100638/288263) which gives what I consider a more robust answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you followed the various Debian update tutorials out there, chances are you ended up with an incorrect /etc/apt/source.list

As most "fixes" are listed sed command patches, they may not work if your original source.list content isn't a perfect match.

In that case, just edit source.list manually, the new bullseye security lines should read like

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
```

or alternatively if you do not need source and want contrib, it could be just

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib
```

Comment: Informative, robust and also correct answer.